# On which SE can I ask theme park related questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, site-recommendation

From an online [theme park survival guide](http://pbskids.org/itsmylife/blog/2013/04/theme-park-survival-guide.html):

> 5) Know the loopholes. Help the adults you're with to read up on the theme park's special time-saving tricks and programs so you can do less waiting in line. Some popular rides, shows, and attractions may have "fast pass" machines so you can get a timed ticket to come back and skip the main line later in the day. Check insider websites and message boards to pinpoint the best day and time to visit certain attractions.

Which SE should I use if have questions about theme parks (Universal Studios Orlando or Disneyland), such as

- Which rides are the "select rides" that the express/fast passes work for?
- Under what weather conditions do the rides close (and which rides)?

***Specific*** questions that are ***NOT*** on the parks' main websites (or are hard to find), You know? Is there a SE for that?

Comment: Do you really need a SE for it? Park hours should be on every park's site... most of that info is already available out there easily or on a wide variety of forums like this one: http://www.disboards.com/forums/theme-parks-attractions-and-strategies.2/.

Comment: Literally all this information is on those parks websites.

Comment: @Catija ok, so maybe park hours was a silly example, but for the other specific questions, I want a SE so I can know if the answerer is "trustworthy" etc.

Comment: Are you seriously saying that the only sites worth trusting on the web are SE sites? Even over forums that specialize in this topic? The only current site I can think of would be travel but I'm pretty certain this is out of their scope.

Comment: It sounds like you are after a site that gives opinions on trustworthiness.  I think that means you are looking in the wrong place because on most SE network sites questions are closed if they seek opinions or are likely to generate opinion-based answers.

Comment: @Ramhound see edits, please

Comment: The SE does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking about available types of rides in a particular theme park in a particular place, and it's timings, then [Travel SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) is the place for it. For example:

> Under what weather conditions do the rides close (and which rides)?

This is mostly a region-specific or a localized question, which the native people would be able to give a definite answer. So, Travel SE can be helpful in this case.

However, this question would be closed off as opinion based:

> Which rides are the "select rides" that the express/fast passes work
>   for?

Questions like this, would be welcome though:

Are there any rides which < `Description/type of your desired ride` > in this < `theme park name` > at < `location where the theme park is located` >?